# Why does Django need a request object in rendering a template?

Tags: django, django-templates

Why does Django need a request object in rendering a template?

```
 return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

Comment: Technically, [it doesn't](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `request` argument is used if you want to use a `RequestContext` which is usually the case when you want to use [template context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#built-in-template-context-processors). You can pass in `None` as the `request` argument if you want and you will get a regular `Context` object in your template.

Answer (score 4):

As per [the docs about render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render):

> Combines a given template with a given context dictionary and returns
>   an HttpResponse object with that rendered text.

Thus it's meant to be used in views, where you have a `request` object and need to return an [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse). A typical use case is when you build the context from the request.

If you only need to render a template, you can use the shortcut function `render_to_string`:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

render_to_string('your_template.html', {'some_key':'some_value'})
```

Or do it manually:

```
from django.template import Context, Template 

Template('your_template.html').render(Context({'some_key':'some_value'})
```

Comment: docu said request is required parameter?  Is  Template('your_template.html').render(Context({'some_key':'some_value'})using  a different render method?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is b/c the `render()` shortcut is using a [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)

You could also use [get_template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.get_template) directly and call [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Template.render) with a normal [Context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Context)